# Bootstrap/Css vertical Navbar should display submenu onclick instead of hover

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, css, navbar

**Bootstrap/Css vertical Navbar should display submenu onclick instead of hover**

I am having a Vertical Navigation bar which displays submenus on hover. Instead of hover I want it on click . Any ways to do that with pure css/bootstrap?

```css
.navigation {
  width: 300px;
}


.mainmenu, .submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.mainmenu a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #CCC;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
}


.mainmenu a:hover {
    background-color: #C5C5C5;
}

.mainmenu li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.submenu a {
  background-color: #999;
}


.submenu a:hover {
  background-color: #666;
}


.submenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li><a href="">Home</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Tops</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Bottoms</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Footwear</a></li>
      </ul></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Tops</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Bottoms</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Footwear</a></li>
      </ul></li>
    <li><a href="">Products</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Tops</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Bottoms</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Footwear</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: No, CSS doesn't support click events.

Comment: use jquery for this

Comment: You need to use jQuery to achieve this behaviour.

Comment: It's easily done with Bootstrap using the collapse component: http://www.bootply.com/1Ymhk06o0l

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".mainmenu li").click(function(){
  $(".mainmenu li").removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.navigation {
  width: 300px;
}


.mainmenu, .submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.mainmenu a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #CCC;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
}


.mainmenu a:hover {
    background-color: #C5C5C5;
}

.mainmenu li.active .submenu {
  display: block;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.submenu a {
  background-color: #999;
}


.submenu a:hover {
  background-color: #666;
}


.submenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Tops</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Bottoms</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Footwear</a></li>
      </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Tops</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Bottoms</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Footwear</a></li>
      </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Tops</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Bottoms</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Footwear</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Using few lines of jQuery code you can achieve the behaviour you are expecting.